# Was bedeutet „enttäuschungsfest“?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Ich habe den Begriff in einer Vorlesung gehört und er kommt auch in [diesem Zeit-Artikel](http://www.zeit.de/2000/34/200034_tv-kritik.xml) vor. Ich habe zwar Vermutungen, aber da ich den Begriff nirgendwo anders finden kann und er auch nicht im Duden steht, bin ich mir nicht sicher, was er bedeutet.

Comment: Gleichartig zu "ironiedicht".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In der Soziologie scheint der Begriff nicht neu zu sein, so finden sich bei [Google](https://www.google.de/search?q=entt%C3%A4uschungsfest&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=SEjEVv-OK4GcygPc2qS4CQ#q=entt%C3%A4uschungsfest%20soziologie) einige Bücher und Artikel mit dem Begriff.

Die Definition von Enttäuschungsfestigkeit in der Wirtschaftssoziologie lautet dabei:

> Erwartungen sind enttäuschungsfest, wenn und soweit sie auch angesichts gegenteiliger Erfahrungen aufrechterhalten werden. ([Quelle](http://www.wirtschaftslexikon.co/d/enttaeuschungsfestigkeit/enttaeuschungsfestigkeit.htm))

In meinen Worten würde ich "enttäuschungsfest" so beschreiben:

Ich erwarte, dass mein Freundin pünklich ist. Sie ist es aber nie. Trotzdem warte ich jedesmal pünklich auf sie am Treffpunkt, weil ich erwarte, dass sie diesesmal pünktlich ist. Das mache ich aber nur solange ich enttäuschungsfest bin. Wenn ich nicht enttäuschungsfest bin, dann wäre ich wütent/enttäuscht/traurig, wenn sie zu spät kommt und würde das nächste Mal wohl nicht mehr.

Dazu passt auch dieser Spruch:

> Enttäuschungsfestigkeit kann bei der Freundschaft zu Menschen generell ein guter Garant sein. ([Quelle](http://www.mus4.net/kategorie-feuilleton/gesellschaft/339-entt%C3%A4uschungsfestigkeit.html))

Comment: Das scheint tatsächlich die Bedeutung zu sein die ich gesucht hatte (der Begriff fiel im Rahmen einer Soziologieveranstaltung). Mein Verständnis von dem Begriff ist aber ein anderer - enttäuscht ist man immer wenn man Pünktlichkeit erwartet - ob man enttäuschungsfest ist oder nicht - aber wenn man nicht enttäuschungsfest ist, würde man seine Erwartungen (Pünktlichkeit) dem beobachteten Verhalten (Verspätung) anpassen anstatt weiterhin Pünktlichkeit zu erwarten.

(Das ist vielleicht sogar was die Antwort jetzt gerade aussagt, vielleicht lese ich das nur falsch).

Comment: @Cubic, ja, so könnte man es auch verstehen. Entweder man ist enttäuscht und ändert trotzdem nichts, oder man ist nicht (arg genug) enttäuscht und ändert deswegen nichts. Ich bin kein Soziologe, ich weiß daher nicht was richtig ist. Die Definition passt meiner Meinung nach auf beides.

Answer (score 0):

Das scheint mir eine Wortneuschöpfung der Autoren zu sein. Bedeutung kann ich auch nur vermuten, liegt aber nahe: "enttäuschungsfest" im gleichen Sinnkontext wie "wasserfest".

Answer (score 0):

Enttäuschungsfest würde ich am ehesten als die Fähigkeit oder Eigenschaft bezeichnen, von bestimmten, nicht erfüllten Erwartungen oder Hoffnungen nicht enttäuscht zu werden. Ein ähnliches Wort wäre für mich beispielsweise resolut (wenn resolut eventuell auch etwas zu selbstbewusst im Vergleich zu enttäuschungsfest – was ja relativ neutral ist – sein könnte).

In dem Artikel über Ellen wird enttäuschungsfest meiner Meinung nach auch am ehesten als standhaft und selbstironisch genutzt, was wieder näher an resolut heranrückt.

Ähnliche (nicht synonyme!) Wörter mit tendenziell negativerem Sinn wären beispielsweise *abgebrüht* oder *abgestumpft*.

Answer (score 0):

I am understanding the the correct meaning is similar to "disappointment-proof", or as we might say: satisfaction guaranteed. I don't know if people will be amused that as an English speaker, I interpreted the suffix "-fest" as in Oktoberfest, so I was reading it as a celebration of disappointment...something like a get-together where everyone wallows in each others' misery. It kind of sounded like fun in a way.

By the way, a "sausagefest" in English a social gathering (often in a bar or nightclub) with a paucity of females. Not a good thing. I can explain the source of the expression if anyone thinks it is necessary.

Comment: That seems more like a comment than an answer. We've already discussed the meaning in other answers, and "satisfaction guarantee" doesn't quite cover what is meant by the expression.

Answer (score -2):

Wie bereits gesagt wurde: Es scheint eine Art von Wortschöpfung zu sein. 
Spielt wahrscheinlich auch Marketingbegriff wie "wasserfest" an.

"Wasserfest" soll bedeuten, dass es keine Probleme mit Wasser gibt. Resistent gegen Wasser ist.

Hier will man anscheinend ausdrücken, dass es keine Probleme mit Enttäuschungen gibt. Das Ganze resistent gegen Enttäuschungen ist.

By the way:

Ist komisches Zeugs von irgendwelchen Journalisten. Würde ich nicht zu wichtig nehmen. So einen Quatsch redet kein normaler Mensch.

Comment: Ist es eine Worschöpfung oder eine Wortschöpungsart? Ganze Sätze? Von Journalisten enttäuscht?